# What is .Net Unicode Encoding's equivalent in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, unicode

What is the equivalent in Objective-C of .Net's `System.Text.Encoding.Unicode`?
I have tried:

- NSUnicodeStringEncoding
- NSUTF8StringEncoding
- NSUTF16StringEncoding

None of the above converted the text back correctly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.text.encoding.unicode.aspx, `System.Text.Encoding.Unicode` is the little-endian UTF-16 encoding. The equivalent `NSString` encoding is `NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding`.

`NSUTF16StringEncoding` is *almost* the same, but prepends a Unicode Byte-Order Marker (BOM) `FF FE` to the data. (And strictly speaking, it is not documented that `NSUTF16StringEncoding` uses little-endian, so the explicit `NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding` should be used anyway.)

Comment: +1 thax it helped me to resolve my problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19110360/net-vs-objective-c-sha-512-mismatch)