# .net vs Objective c SHA-512 mismatch

Tags: ios, .net, objective-c, sha512

I am trying to write function for creating sha512 string in objective from .net function which is

```
public static string GetSHA512(string strPlain)
{
    UnicodeEncoding UE = new UnicodeEncoding();
    byte[] HashValue = null;
    byte[] MessageBytes = UE.GetBytes(strPlain);
    System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512Managed SHhash = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512Managed();
    string strHex = string.Empty;

    HashValue = SHhash.ComputeHash(MessageBytes);
    foreach (byte b in HashValue)
    {
        strHex += String.Format("{0:x2}", b);
    }
    return strHex;
}
```

This gives result as

```
input : pass123
output: 2a6353744cc2914c602265f50d2e413d0561368775756392517abb340ef75d52ee0c5d3623ddd1826fd768a13dca8961f5957c75df0d793b9d7537aabe050705
```

What I have tried is as follow

```
-(NSString *)createSHA512:(NSString *)string
{
    const char *cstr = [string cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:cstr length:string.length];
    uint8_t digest[CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_SHA512(data.bytes, data.length, digest);
    NSMutableString* output = [NSMutableString  stringWithCapacity:CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    for(int i = 0; i < CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
        [output appendFormat:@"%02x", digest[i]];
    return output;
}
```

which gives result below

```
input : pass123
output: fd37ca5ca8763ae077a5e9740212319591603c42a08a60dcc91d12e7e457b024f6bdfdc10cdc1383e1602ff2092b4bc1bb8cac9306a9965eb352435f5dfe8bb0
```

Can anyone please suggest what am I doing wrong ?

Why these two values differ ?

Please correct my mistakes.

**EDIT**

Mean While I have tried changing encoding to `NSUTF16StringEncoding` and `NSUnicodeStringEncoding` which results still different and as follows

```
input : pass123
output: 514331e3f7ca0a295539347ebccc4e4f095fe5f3c1df10d43b4d550144c7b30ba9507831893ea63ea22e62e993be529b0d14be7800a90aa0de199d6be62a5f1b
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Little bit of trial and error in function and searching for [compitable version of encoding found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16624685/what-is-net-unicode-encodings-equivalent-in-objective-c) help me to resolve problem.

In function conversion to const char was not necessary so removed and directly converted string to data using default method available.

```
-(NSString *)createSHA512:(NSString *)string {
    NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding];
    uint8_t digest[CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_SHA512(data.bytes, data.length, digest);
    NSMutableString* output = [NSMutableString  stringWithCapacity:CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    for(int i = 0; i < CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
        [output appendFormat:@"%02x", digest[i]];
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In the Objective C version you're converting the text to binary using UTF-8. In the .NET version you're using UTF-16. That may not be the *only* difference, but it's certainly a relevant one.

I'd rewrite your .NET method as:

```
public static string GetSHA512(string text)
{
    byte[] messageBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);

    byte[] hash;
    using (SHA512 hashAlgorithm = SHA512.Create())
    {
        hash = hashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(messageBytes);
    }

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (byte b in hash)
    {
        builder.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
    }        
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response but we are in a stage where we cannot change .net function and need to write compitable function in objective c.

Comment: @JanakNirmal So simply do: `const char *cstr = [string cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding];`

Comment: @JanakNirmal: It would have been worth saying that to start with. In that case you need to change your Objective C code to use `NSUTF16StringEncoding`.

Comment: I have already tried mean while when I responded to answer but the result is still different. Updated question accordingly. Thax for your input though.

Answer (score 0):

For base64encoded string:

```
-(NSString *)createSHA512Net:(NSString *)string {
    NSData *data = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding];
    uint8_t digest[CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_SHA512(data.bytes, data.length, digest);
    NSData *out = [NSData dataWithBytes:digest length:CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    NSString *str = [out  base64EncodedStringWithOptions:kNilOptions]; 
    return str;
}
```